# How to know in which country a domain name is registered?

Tags: dns, registration

I have a stupid question, I am exploring these things so I may not be able to formulate my question using technical terms, but I want to know How can one check in which country a domain name is registered? and Does it matter? Lets say I am in Singapore but I register a domain name in Germany for my website does it matter?

Thanks ALL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple "**whois**" on the domain name" : **whois abc.com** or check this website http://www.whois.net/ , that should do the trick. It does not matter where you register the domain, as most likely you will be pointing this to your IP scheme wherever you have hosting.