# How to find out who has registered some domain name?

Tags: dns, subdomain

One can easily check that the domain name is registered but, how to find out who has registred some domain name i.e. abcd.com etc. Or in other words How can one find out the particulars of the person or company who registered a domain and where is it operating from?

Thanks all!

Comment: Run `whois domain.name` from console in operation system that you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712322/how-to-know-in-which-country-a-domain-name-is-registered (same OP)

Comment: Both are different question please read the question and there description.

Comment: Whois is not giving a correct information it is usually vague. There is another thing called Traceroute command but it is not giving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try here  https://www.name.com/domain/search :) you can also check out on whois here: http://www.whois.net/

Keep in mind that depending on the entity who registered the domain, some info might not be available. If its a big company, the name of who registered the domain wont appear, but the info about where the company is located will apear for example.

Comment: Whois is not giving the address and details of the person or company who registered the domain. I guess there is some option from which one can hide this information.